# Transposing quarters as row to column using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data that contains Quarters as rows.

Is it possible to convert 7 Quarters into **columns** using **BigQuery**?

My data :
[image]

Desired output :
[image]

Methods used by me :

1. Offset clause
2. 

```
    Select Name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN QuarterEnding ='Q1, 2020' THEN  AT END) Q12020,
        SUM(CASE WHEN QuarterEnding='Q2, 2020' THEN AT END) Q22020,
        SUM(CASE WHEN QuarterEnding='Q3, 2020' THEN AT END) Q32020,
        SUM(CASE WHEN QuarterEnding='Q4, 2020' THEN AT END) Q42020,
    FROM `table1`
    GROUP by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Pi-R mentioned, example query in the documentation is very close to what you want but for your specific desired output, you might consider below.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(City) FROM `table1`
) PIVOT (
  SUM(`AT`) FOR TRANSLATE(QuarterEnding, ', ', '')
             IN ('Q12020', 'Q22020', 'Q32020', 'Q42020',
                 'Q12021', 'Q22021', 'Q32021', 'Q42021')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. You teach me the `TRANSLATE` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at pivot function of BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator. There is the same use case as yours

First you have to rename quarter's name so they can be a field.

```
Q1, 2020 => Q12020
```

Then you can use

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
 PIVOT(min(ID) FOR QuarterEnding IN ('Q12020', 'Q22020', 'Q32020', 'Q42020','Q12021', 'Q22021', 'Q32021', 'Q42021'))
```

Comment: My case is slightly different because I require Quarter n year (like Q1,2020) as a column.